# Can not load my script in plugin for frontend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

When I put this code before `get_header()` it loaded the script, but when put it after `get_header()`, it does not work. I should tell you that I use this in plugin that I want to use it in frontend.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );

function my_enqueue($hook) { 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/my_query.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );

    // in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest placing your code snippet in the functions.php file of your theme and enqueing it. This will ensure it is loaded properly as WordPress runs.

[An example of WordPress enqueing](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/):

```
wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', string[] $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```

You will want to make sure this script loads after jQuery.

Comment: When i put it in functions.php it will be loaded to all of my pages but i just need it in one page i used `$(docuemnt).ready(fubnction(){}` for scroll down loading then it will be fire on all pages with many ajax request to server and make slow the website and that is not good any solution to be able load it in my custom page only

Comment: One thing you can try doing is before wp_enqueue_script(), you can check if it is the correct page with the is_page() condition. https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page